The question about the existence of an infinite non-trivial controversy
I wonder if there are some examples in mathematics or non-mathematics of two people who cannot settle an argument, or in other words, what I am specifically looking for is that every argument one of these two people makes has a counter-argument from the other person and this argument goes on forever. Even though these two people have an infinite number of arguments, neither of them can come up with a conclusive argument. I would be happy if someone could prove that such a case is impossible, or provide a way to generate such arguments. Are there things that cannot be determined as true or false because there are an infinite number of opposing arguments that cannot be settled.

I know this, my question is, assuming this kind of barrier is overcome, can this kind of thing exist? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Existence in the realm of logic, such as the existence of infinity in mathematics @MauroALLEGRANZA

The English phrase "agree to disagree" is for such cases, so we know that they arise. For relationships, we have the phrase "irreconcilable differences".

An infinite argument can be constructed using circular reasoning or infinite regression. It's unclear though what counts as "non-trivial" in the question.
An example story for circular dialogue is the song There's a hole in my bucket.
There, the solution of the initial problem requires several sequential steps, the last of which would be the same as the first, causing a circle of dependencies.
An example for infinite regress are Zenos paradoxes, exemplified in the story What the tortoise said to Achilles
There, a clever tortoise could forever generate new premises that need to be fulfilled before accepting the target one.

Both those examples can be resolved (i.e. handled to the point of there being nothing new that can be contributed). The hole-in-the-bucket can be resolved by looking at the set of dependencies as a whole. Zeno's paradox can be resolved by using more advance math.

Yes, as I said "non-trivially" is unclear in the question. I agree in some sense those are trivial examples.

Isn't there an infinitely regressing argument in Godel Escher Bach?

Here is a little set-theoretic example. Suppose you and I are arguing about the Continuum Hypothesis (CH).
You say that you think there is a model of ZFC, the Zermelo-Frankel axioms with the Axiom of Choice, in which CH is false.
I respond: "No, your model is too small, too short-sighted about how many sets there are. I can build a bigger model of ZFC in which CH is true."
Then you respond: "No, it's your model which is too small. I can build an even bigger model of ZFC in which CH is false."
Then I respond: "No, it's your model which is too small. I can build a model of ZFC which is even bigger still, in which CH is true."
This can go on without bound. What's going on is that, if there exists a model M for ZFC, then there exists a larger model of ZFC, a so-called "forcing extension of M", in which the CH is false. This is how Paul Cohen proved, in 1963, that the negation of CH is consistent with ZFC. Similarly, if there exists a model M for ZFC, then there exists a forcing extension of M in which CH is true. So you can bounce back and forth indefinitely, building larger and larger models for ZFC--at least, if there exists any model for ZFC at all!--in which CH is alternately true, then false, then true, etc.
That is, CH is an example of what Hamkins and Loewe call a "switch": it's a statement that can always be made to be true or false by passing to a forcing extension--it's like flipping a switch, you can turn it on or off.

This question feels somewhat vague, what does it mean to settle an arguement? What limitations do people have? Can they construct additional terms or build a science department? Are they allowed to rephrase the original disagreement? Depending on the answers, we could just give https://slate.com/technology/2017/04/heres-why-people-saw-the-dress-differently.html as an example and argue physiology leads to different irreconcilable view points.
Alternatively there is hard-core maths, where you get Godel's incompleteness theorem, which says that: for sufficiently complex systems there are statements that cannot be proven true or false in the system.
And related, there is the Halting problem, which says it is impossible to construct a program that can look at an algorithm and answer if it will eventually stop.
However, for these mathematics answers infinities are occurring somewhere.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
